# nroff/groff does not properly convert utf-8 encoded file

Tags: linux, encoding, utf-8

I am having a utf-8 encoded roff-file that I want to convert to a manpage with

```
$ nroff -mandoc inittab.5
```

However, characters in `[äöüÄÖÜ]`, e.g. are not displayed properly as it seems that nroff assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding (I am getting `[Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃÃÃ`] instead. Calling `nroff` with the `-Tutf8` flag does not change the behaviour and the locale environment variables are (I assume properly) set to

```
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Since `nroff` is only a wrapper-script and eventually calls `groff` I checked the call to the latter which is:

```
$ groff -Tutf8 -mandoc inittab.5
```

Comparing the byte-encodings of characters in the src file and the output file I am getting the following conversions:

```
character  src file  output file
---------  --------  -----------
ä          C3 A4     C3 83 C2 A4
ö          C3 B6     C3 83 C2 B6
ü          C3 BC     C3 83 C2 BC
Ä          C3 84     C3 83
Ö          C3 96     C3 83
Ü          C3 9C     C3 83
ß          C3 9F     C3 83
```

This behaviour seems very weird to me (why am I getting an additional `C3 83` and have the original byte-sequence truncated alltogether for big umlauts and `ß`?)

Why is this and how can I make `nroff`/`groff` properly convert my utf-8 encoded file?

EDIT: I am using `GNU nroff (groff) version 1.22.2`

Comment: When you run say `less inittab.5` do you see proper characters? By the way the question is off topic for this site, you may have better luck at unix/linux stackexchange.

Comment: Yes! Everything is fine with the input file.

Comment: Evidently nroff thinks its *input* is Latin-1 and tries to transcode it to UTF-8. Try running with -Tlatin1 to avoid transcoding.

Comment: It looks like groff doesn't support UTF-8 input at all. https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Input-Encodings.html

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How come most of my Gentoo programs come with utf-8 encoded man pages then? I could convert them to latin1, but that would ommit other characters. Are you aware of a nroff alternative that supports utf-8 input?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike other troff implementations (namely Plan 9 and Heirloom troff), groff does not support UTF8 in documents. However, UTF8 output can be achieved using the `preconv(1)` pre-processor, which converts UTF8 characters in a file to groff native escape sequences.

Take for example this `groff_ms(7)` document:

```
.TL
StackOverflow Test Document
.AU
ToasterKing
.PP
I like going to the café down the street

äöüÄÖÜ
```

Using `groff` normally, we get:

```
                StackOverflow Test Document


                        ToasterKing


     I like going to the cafÃ© down the street

Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃÃÃ
```

But when using `preconv | groff` or `groff -k`, we get:

```
                StackOverflow Test Document


                        ToasterKing


     I like going to the café down the street

äöüÄÖÜ
```

Looking at the output of `preconv`, you can see how it transforms characters into escape sequences:

```
.lf 1 so.ms
.TL
StackOverflow Test Document
.AU
ToasterKing
.PP
I like going to the caf\[u00E9] down the street

\[u00E4]\[u00F6]\[u00FC]\[u00C4]\[u00D6]\[u00DC]
```